# Vector names error

Tags: r, function, vector, names

Im trying to set names for a vector using the function `names`, but R gives me an error. I want to create a vector with function and then set name for each number in that vector. I want to do all this step by writing just one order (for example `v(x)`). This is example of my code script

```
v <- c(2,6,5)
d <- function(x) x*9

names(d(x))<-paste("q=", 1:3, sep="")
```

and R says

> Error in names(d(x)) <- paste("q=", 1:3, sep = "") : 
>     could not find function "d<-"

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and desired output.

Comment: Maybe try actually storing the result of `div(x)` in a variable first before setting the names...?

Comment: maybe mark correct to close it out and get it off the unanswered list? Or do you still need help on this?

Comment: If you solved it differently then add that as a solution and mark that correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what you are doing, but assuming this approximates it I can reproduce the error:

```
qn <- 1:11

div_1 <- function(x) { x <- x + 1 }
div_2 <- function(x) { x <- x + 2 }

div<- function(x) c(div_1(x)[1],div_2(x),div_1(x)[2:10])
x <- 1
names(div(x))<- paste("q=", qn, sep="" )
# Error in names(div(x)) <- paste("q=", qn, sep = "") : 
#  could not find function "div<-"
```

and I can fix it with this (breaking it into two steps):

```
qn <- 1:11

div_1 <- function(x) { x <- x + 1 }
div_2 <- function(x) { x <- x + 2 }

div<- function(x) c(div_1(x)[1],div_2(x),div_1(x)[2:10])

x <- 1

v <- div(x)
names(v)<- paste("q=", qn, sep="" )

# q=1  q=2  q=3  q=4  q=5  q=6  q=7  q=8  q=9 q=10 q=11  
# 2    3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

It may be a bug, or a limitation in assigning names to a temporary variable (note that the result gets thrown out in your version). Out of curiousity, what are you doing with div?

Comment: Yep I always made this step with same output. Div is function for computing diversity (biological stuffs).

Comment: So did this fix it for you?

Comment: Nope, but now I fixed that a liitle different. v<<-div(x), names(v)<-....
this works but i wanted to have a function with this output. Now i have to post two commands instead of one. Those commands are div(x) and v

Comment: Would help if you explained what is wrong with mine, and how you fixed it.

Comment: sorry, it doesnt work. the output v has different nubers than div(x)

Comment: I think I see. You should have posted it as a function then. Try and post complete examples in the future, it will help insure against downvotes.

Comment: Sorry for that. Can i delete this question and post it again after upgrades?

Comment: @Bobesh All your posts are editable. Never delete a question just to repost it. Just edit.